# Why does my program not update the XML file immediately?

Tags: java, arrays, xml, netbeans

I'm new to this site so I'd appreciate it if you could be patient with me. :)
I'm in the process of perfecting a sort of study-tool program that I am making. 
The user can input a question/answer information into the settings (like you can do in Quizlet). To save the program you have to click on the "save" button.

But for some reason, the XML file (where the question/answer is stored) only updates after you click the save button THEN stop running the program, then run the program again.

[In short, the updated information doesn't show on the textboxes until after the program is closed then reopened again.]

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pkg1051037_chang_chinesejeopardygame;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


/**
 *
 * @author 장리나
 */

public class ParseXMlFile {
    private DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory;
    private DocumentBuilder builder;
    private Document document;
    private File inputFile;

    public static List<QuestionDetails> questionDetailsList;

    // parses the xml file
    public ParseXMlFile()  {
        // the try statement gets the different question details
        try {
            inputFile = new File("QuestionDetails.xml");
            builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(inputFile);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            // the catch statement stops the program when there is no value
            Logger.getLogger(ParseXMlFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            // catch statement stops the program when there is no value
            Logger.getLogger(ParseXMlFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // catch statement stops the program when there is no value
            Logger.getLogger(ParseXMlFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    public void addNode(String questionId, String question, String multipleChoice1, String multipleChoice2, String multipleChoice3, String rightAnswerChoice)
    {
      //

    }

    // updates the question details to xml file (edits preexisting info)
    public boolean updateQuestionDetailsToXML(String questionId, String question, String multipleChoice1, String multipleChoice2, String multipleChoice3, String rightAnswerChoice) {
        boolean success = false;

        try {
            // Get the questionDetails Tag
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.QUESTION_DETAILS_TAG);

            for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element questionElement = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                NamedNodeMap nodeMapAttr = questionElement.getAttributes();
                Node attrNode = nodeMapAttr.getNamedItem(JeopardyConstants.ID_TAG);

                if (attrNode.getNodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase(questionId)) {
                   // update the question
                   NodeList questionNodeList = questionElement.getChildNodes();
                   for (int j = 0; j < questionNodeList.getLength(); j++) {
                       Node childNode = questionNodeList.item(j);
                       if (childNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.QUESTION_TAG)) {
                           childNode.setTextContent(question);
                       }
                   }
                   String rightChoice1 = "N";
                   String rightChoice2 = "N";
                   String rightChoice3 = "N";
                   // update the multipleChoices
                   if (rightAnswerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE1_TAG)) {
                       rightChoice1 = "Y";
                   } else if (rightAnswerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE2_TAG)) {
                       rightChoice2 = "Y";
                   } else if (rightAnswerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE3_TAG)) {
                       rightChoice3 = "Y";
                   }
                   // Update multiple choice 1
                   updateMultipleChoiceDetails(questionElement, questionId, JeopardyConstants.CHOICE1_TAG, multipleChoice1, rightChoice1);
                   updateMultipleChoiceDetails(questionElement, questionId, JeopardyConstants.CHOICE2_TAG, multipleChoice2, rightChoice2);
                   updateMultipleChoiceDetails(questionElement, questionId, JeopardyConstants.CHOICE3_TAG, multipleChoice3, rightChoice3);
                }

            }
            updateXML(); // update the xml file
            // loop through the question details
            for (QuestionDetails questionDetails : questionDetailsList) {
                if (questionDetails.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(questionId)) {
                    questionDetails.setQuestion(question);
                }
            }
            success = true;
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            // if success is not equal to true
            Logger.getLogger(ParseXMlFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return success;

    }

    // fix this part below? (empty method)
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void addNewEntry(String questionId, String newQuestion, String choice1Answer, String choice2Answer,String choice3Answer) {
    }

    private void updateMultipleChoiceDetails(Element questionElement, String questionId, String choiceName, String updatedValue, String rightAnswer) {
        NodeList choiceNodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(choiceName);

        for (int k = 0; k < choiceNodeList.getLength(); k++) {
            Element choiceElement = (Element) choiceNodeList.item(k);

            // get the child nodes
            NodeList choiceChildrenList = choiceElement.getChildNodes();

            for (int m = 0; m < choiceChildrenList.getLength(); m++) {
                if (choiceChildrenList.item(m).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element choiceChild = (Element) choiceChildrenList.item(m);
                    String nodeName = choiceChild.getTagName();
                    // Update the value/choice details
                    if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.VALUE_TAG)) {
                        choiceChild.getFirstChild().setTextContent(updatedValue);
                        for (QuestionDetails questionDetails : questionDetailsList) {
                            if (questionDetails.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(questionId)) {
                                // Update to QuestionDetails Object
                                if (choiceName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE1_TAG)) {
                                    questionDetails.setMultipleChoice1(updatedValue);
                                } else if (choiceName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE2_TAG)) {
                                    questionDetails.setMultipleChoice2(updatedValue);
                                } else if (choiceName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE3_TAG)) {
                                    questionDetails.setMultipleChoice3(updatedValue);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    // WORK IN PROGRESS -- DOES NOT WORK YET
                    if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CORRECT_TAG)) {
                        // Update the 'correct' tag if the answer choice is the correct answer
                        choiceChild.getFirstChild().setTextContent(rightAnswer);
                        for (QuestionDetails questionDetails : questionDetailsList) {
                            if (questionDetails.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(questionId)) {
                                questionDetails.setRightAnswer(updatedValue);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void updateXML() throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(inputFile);
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
    }
    public void parseXML() {
        questionDetailsList = new ArrayList<QuestionDetails>();

        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.QUESTION_DETAILS_TAG);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element questionElement = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            String attribute = questionElement.getAttribute(JeopardyConstants.ID_TAG);
            QuestionDetails questionDetails = new QuestionDetails();
            questionDetails.setId(attribute);

            NodeList levelNodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.LEVEL_TAG);
            for (int k = 0; k < levelNodeList.getLength(); k++) {
                Element element = (Element) levelNodeList.item(k);
                String nodeName = element.getFirstChild().getNodeName();
                String nodeValue = element.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                //System.out.println(nodeName + ":" + nodeValue);
                questionDetails.setLevel(Integer.parseInt(nodeValue));
            }

            NodeList questionNodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.QUESTION_TAG);
            for (int k = 0; k < questionNodeList.getLength(); k++) {
                Element element = (Element) questionNodeList.item(k);
                String nodeName = element.getFirstChild().getNodeName();
                String nodeValue = element.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                //System.out.println(nodeName + ":" + nodeValue);
                questionDetails.setQuestion(nodeValue);
            }

            NodeList scoreNodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.SCORE_TAG);
            for (int k = 0; k < scoreNodeList.getLength(); k++) {
                Element element = (Element) scoreNodeList.item(k);
                String nodeName = element.getFirstChild().getNodeName();
                String nodeValue = element.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                //System.out.println(nodeName + ":" + nodeValue);
                questionDetails.setScore(Integer.parseInt(nodeValue));
            }

             NodeList choice1NodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE1_TAG);
             for (int k = 0; k < choice1NodeList.getLength(); k++) {
                Element choice1Element = (Element) choice1NodeList.item(k);
                NodeList choice1ChildrenList = choice1Element.getChildNodes();
                for (int m = 0; m < choice1ChildrenList.getLength(); m++) {
                    if (choice1ChildrenList.item(m).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element choice1Child = (Element) choice1ChildrenList.item(m);
                        String nodeName = choice1Child.getTagName();
                        String nodeValue = choice1Child.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                        // System.out.println(">>>>>>:" + nodeName);
                        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.VALUE_TAG)) {
                            questionDetails.setMultipleChoice1(nodeValue);
                        }
                        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CORRECT_TAG) && nodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                            questionDetails.setRightAnswer(questionDetails.getMultipleChoice1());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
             // Get nodelist of tag "choice2"
            NodeList choice2NodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE2_TAG);
            //Loop through the nodelIst
             for (int k = 0; k < choice2NodeList.getLength(); k++) {
                 //Get the first element in the node and get its child nodes
                Element choice2Element = (Element) choice2NodeList.item(k);
                NodeList choice2ChildrenList = choice2Element.getChildNodes();
                //Loop through the child nodes
                for (int m = 0; m < choice2ChildrenList.getLength(); m++) {
                    if (choice2ChildrenList.item(m).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element choice2Child = (Element) choice2ChildrenList.item(m);
                        //get the tag name and the tag value
                        String nodeName = choice2Child.getTagName();
                        String nodeValue = choice2Child.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                        // System.out.println(">>>>>>:" + nodeName);
                        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.VALUE_TAG)) {
                            questionDetails.setMultipleChoice2(nodeValue);
                        }
                        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CORRECT_TAG) && nodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                            questionDetails.setRightAnswer(questionDetails.getMultipleChoice2());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

             NodeList choice3NodeList = questionElement.getElementsByTagName(JeopardyConstants.CHOICE3_TAG);
             for (int k = 0; k < choice3NodeList.getLength(); k++) {
                Element choice3Element = (Element) choice3NodeList.item(k);
                NodeList choice3ChildrenList = choice3Element.getChildNodes();
                for (int m = 0; m < choice3ChildrenList.getLength(); m++) {
                    if (choice3ChildrenList.item(m).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element choice3Child = (Element) choice3ChildrenList.item(m);
                        String nodeName = choice3Child.getTagName();
                        String nodeValue = choice3Child.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                        // System.out.println(">>>>>>:" + nodeName);
                        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.VALUE_TAG)) {
                            questionDetails.setMultipleChoice3(nodeValue);
                        }
                        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(JeopardyConstants.CORRECT_TAG) && nodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                            questionDetails.setRightAnswer(questionDetails.getMultipleChoice3());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }



            questionDetailsList.add(questionDetails);
        }

    }

   /* public static void main(String args[]){
        new ParseXMlFile().parseXML();
        for(int i=0; i<questionDetailsList.size(); i++){
            QuestionDetails detail= questionDetailsList.get(i);
            System.out.println("Question Details--------"+detail.toString());

        }
    }*/


}
```

Comment: Have you tried invoking that parse method *after* you invoked the update method?

Comment: Can you show me how please? :o

Comment: This site isn't a free tutor service where people work with you. The problem is that you are basically expecting people to debug your code without having access to all elements. We would a true [mcve] to understand what is going on overall.

Comment: Never mind, I was being dumb...

Comment: Never say that. It isn't easy to learn programming, and it is also not straight forward to come up with questions here where we can easily help with. In case you found a good solution, consider adding it as self answer. Unless it boils down to "just invoke that other method". Then consider deleting your question, as it is not really of use for any future readers.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found a solution yet though and the invoking parse method doesn't work. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: As said: we would need a [mcve] then. I also believe that most likely, you trying to collect that information would most likely enable you to solve the problem yourself.